# Regex data annotation making model state invalid ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core, data-annotations, modelstate

I have a simple regex data annotation

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"\d{5}", ErrorMessage = "Zipcode must be exactly 5 digits")]
public string Zipcode
{
    get;set;
}
```

When the value of the Zipcode is "12345"

Model.IsValid returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it is used for validation Zip code. The Zip code should contain 5 digits and should not be 00000.
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!00000)[0-9]{5,5}$", ErrorMessage = "Zip code should contain 5 digits")]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I gave Zipcode as an example. My requirement is that, string should have 5 digits. The regex works in a console app with regex.match however in razor pages the model is invalid with the same regex.

Comment: Try this [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{5})$", ErrorMessage = "error Message")] It is usually used in DataAnnotations instead directily.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Still curious why the original regex worked in a console app but not while validating the model.

Comment: I guess this is because it uses different name spaces.

Comment: Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks. My pleasure.